# Is it possible to have 2 network plugins for the kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, cni

while going through the network plugin in Kubernetes I end up with a doubt that it is possible to have two network plugin in the cluster created  with kubeadm tool  or can we have alternate plugin so that if one gets any issue it can automatically use another.  can  someone explain me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a combination of different CNIs for different functionality such as calico for policy and flannel for networking. But you cannot have two different CNIs performing exact same functionality in the same cluster simultaneously.

https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/flannel/flannel

Comment: thank you can you tell which plugin we can use based on the performance ?